# Создание дочернего окна в Java

Tags: javascript, java

Здравствуйте!

Долго искал, в итоге ничего путного не нашел. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки открывалось дополнительное окно, которое, допустим, будет запрашивать пароль или еще что-то. Не знаю, как реализовать.

Жду вашей помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Создаете окно с помощью:

```
JFrame j=new JFrame("Название окна");  
 j.setSize(140,140);  
 j.setVisible(true);
```

Добавляете кнопку:

```
JButton but=new JButton("Кнопка")
```

Добавляете слушатель кнопки:

```
class Listener extends MouseListener{
 Listener(){}  
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}  
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}  
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}  
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}  
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}  
}  
but.addMouseListener(new Listener());
```

После выбираете, по какому событию у Вас будет создаваться новое окно, и меняете.
Например: если Вы хотите, чтобы окно открывалось по нажатию мышки, пишете:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){  
 JFrame k=new JFrame("Название другого окна");  
 k.setSize(140,140);  
 k.setVisible(true);  
}
```

Если Вам нужно добавить несколько кнопок, надо выбрать соответствующий режим, например:
Плавающий режим - при изменении размеров окна, кнопки и панели будут плавать и стараться выстроиться в ряд.

```
j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

После того как создаете окно, регистрируйте на нем кнопки и панели для ввода.